# Can't comment a line in my.cnf

Tags: bash, sed

Problem: in my.cnf file there is a line, looking like this:

```
...
bind-address        = 127.0.0.1
...
```

That must be commented out. I tried to use sed for this:

```
sed -i 's/^[\s\t]*\(bind-address[\s\t]+=.*\)/#$1/g' my.cnf
```

But for some reason it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sed -i 's/^[\s\t]*\(bind-address[\s\t]+=.*\)/#$1/g' my.cnf
```

Has a few mistakes

- `[\s\t]` won't work as `\s` is not recognized inside `[]` and `\s` anyway covers `\t`
- `+` needs to be escaped as BRE is default unless `-E` is used in which case `(` should not be escaped
- `$1` should be `\1`
- `g` is not needed as there can be only single match per line with this regex

So, this is corrected version

```
sed -i 's/^\s*\(bind-address\s\+=.*\)/#\1/' my.cnf
```

or using ERE

```
sed -i -E 's/^\s*(bind-address\s+=.*)/#\1/' my.cnf
```

which can still be simplified to

```
sed -i -E 's/^\s*(bind-address\s+=)/#\1/' my.cnf
```

Comment: or even just `sed -i '/^\s*bind-address\s*=/s/^/#/' my.cnf`. I believe all of this is GNU-specific (or at least non-POSIX) due to use of `\s` shorthand for `[[:space:]]`.

Comment: yeah `\s` is GNU specific, didn't mention as OP was using it... there is slight difference in your version, it won't remove the optional spaces at start of line, I thought OP might want that and hence left it as such...

Answer (score 1):

Try with shorter and easier sed command, like ...

`sed -i -e 's/bind-address/\#bind-address/g' my.cnf`

You have not to use regex and others, because bind-address is only used once in my.cnf, there is no other line starting with that and so on, this little bit dirty or lazy approach is a working one.

Comment: There's no reason to escape `#`, it's not a metacharacter.

Answer (score 0):

@Sundeep's answer is very clear and understandable. Just as a supplement. A work around could be

```
sed -i 's/^\s*\(bind-address\s\{1,\}=.*\)/#\1/' my.cnf
```

`+` could be mimicked by `\{1,\}`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use space/tabs character class (and backreference to avoid repetition):

```
sed -i 's/^\([[:space:]]*\)bind-address\1*/#&/' file
```